# sshd issue (maybe ChallengeResponseAuthentication or 'unknown key type' related)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

After adding a new user and his pub key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, I couldn't ssh to my slice (Permission denied (publickey)).

So I changed (in /etc/ssh/sshd_config) ChallengeResponseAuthentication from **no** to **yes** and added him to AllowUsers. Then, after trying to ssh: Connection closed by my.IP.here

So I changed ChallengeResponseAuthentication back to no,

```
`sudo kill `cat /var/run/sshd.pid` && /usr/sbin/sshd`
```

and since then I can't log in with my admin user (**piotr**): Connection closed by my.IP.here.

```
$ ssh -p my.port.here piotr@my.IP.here -vvv
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7l 28 Sep 2006
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to my.IP.here [my.IP.here] port my.port.here.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/piotr/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/piotr/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /Users/piotr/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/piotr/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by my.IP.here
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in that log:

> unknown key type '-----BEGIN'

Seems like you somehow messed up your private key and ssh is no longer able to read it.

Comment: Manni, thanks for your input. Log message is quite clear, although it wasn't a problem. Soft reboot helped, without any changes in configuration, frustrating... And now I can log in, even though  'unknown key type' remains.

Answer (score 0):

unknown key type '-----BEGIN' appears even in normal connections. It's not something bad. I also get these:
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'Proc-Type:'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'DEK-Info:'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'

in all of my connections (public key auth or not)